# How do I test a method defined within a functional component, that interacts with DOM elements and has no arguments

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have been having trouble getting 100% test coverage on one of my buttons (A React functional components.) Basically when it is clicked, it executes some code and then also calls another method from within this `onClick` called `resetButtons`. This method will find all the buttons like it in the app and remove a class. This is a preemptive behavior so that only one button at a time can be `active`.

So far I have tested the click using `.simulate`, passing in a mocked `domElement`. And then test that the `domElement.classList.add` method is called with `'active'`.

Obviously this being a DOM centered operation, I am finding it very difficult to test the `resetButtons` method that lies within the component. especially considering it doesn't have any methods.

I have tried defining the `resetButtons` method outside of the component and then exported it so the jest test could import it. However I have been unable to test the method as it seems to want it to be a spy or mock, and not the method itself. (`Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function`
)

Here is the react Functional Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classes from './MainButton.module.scss';

const MainButton = (props) => {
  const resetButtons = () => {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('mainButton');
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
      elements[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  };

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('active')) {
      resetButtons();
      event.target.classList.add('active');
      props.setVisualState(props.className.split('-')[0]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <button
      onClick={handleClick}
      type="button"
      className={`${classes.mainButton} ${props.className}`}
    >
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};

MainButton.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  setVisualState: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

MainButton.defaultProps = {
  children: 'Button',
  className: '',
};

export default MainButton;
```

Here is the Test

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import MainButton from './MainButton';

describe('MainButton', () => {
  const domElement = { classList: { contains: jest.fn(), remove: jest.fn(), add: jest.fn() } };
  const setVisualStateMock = jest.fn();
  const mainButton = shallow(<MainButton setVisualState={setVisualStateMock} />);

  it(' is rendered properly', () => {
    expect(mainButton).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  describe('when clicked', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      mainButton.find('button').simulate('click', { target: domElement });
    });

    it('it runs `classlist.add` to assign `active` class', () => {
      expect(domElement.classList.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith('active');
    });

    it('it runs set visual state to update `Allergen` container `state`', () => {
      expect(setVisualStateMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Currently the coverage report is reporting 92% coverage, but the branch is at 50 and the line that is causing the trouble is on line 9 (the `elements[i].classList.remove('active');` line.

I know at 90% I should probably just move on but this is something I want to be able to figure out. Feel like getting head around this will make me a better tested.

Hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fumbling around in the DOM yourself is an anti-pattern. That's React's job. Instead of manipulating the dom with `target.classList.add` you should have a state property that holds the status which of your inputs is currently active. Then, while rendering you can say `className={isActiveInput ? "active": null}`.

Because the state is not specific to your MainButton component you would [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). If you have the state somewhere in the parent you don't have to crudely search for DOM elements by classname and manipulate the dom yourself.

Simply put, the rule of React is: You define how things are supposed to look like, React takes care that your definition becomes reality in the dom. If you manipulate the DOM yourself - you're doing it wrong.

When all of this is done, you will have no problem at all with tests, because all you have to do is provide the proper state and props, which is easy, and check that your callback is triggered onClick.

EDIT: Advanced version would be to use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), but I'd go with state lifting first.

Comment: I agree with how you explained everything. But was just wondering why you mentioned context ? That looks a bit out of the scope of the problem. Can you touch upon that a bit ?

Comment: Sure, instead of lifting state up and handing it down through potential multiple levels of components, context would allow to put the state into context and then inject the context, where required. (anyway, spamming contexts is probably a bad idea for small things like this, lifting state should be enough)

Comment: Thank you so much konqi, this really makes sense in my head, and will be something I keep in mind in the future. (I should always explore how the code is behaving if I cant test it without going into more complicated means.) And the thought about not using dom manipulation in react sounds so obviously now you say it out loud. A great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to mount multiple `MainButton`s, click one and expect that the other(s) had `domElement.classList.remove` called on them.

However, user konqi is right in that React provides better ways of manipulating elements/components.

You could replace this test:

```
expect(domElement.classList.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith('active');
```

with a test that checks that the button has (or does not have) the `active` className (instead of checking that the function was called with the right argument). With that test in place, if you like, you could refactor this in the way that konqi suggests.

Comment: yes, well, the real issue is that even if the tests become green the component WILL misbehave. If I understand correctly, there will be multiple dom elements with the class `mainButton`. Each of which will manipulate the classes property of the others. BUT, upon re-render by react, those changes will be lost because they don't exist in the virtual DOM. This will cause so much headache in the long term, I just couldn't bring myself to say what is needed to make the test work as it is.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion but as you said, I think konqi's answer is definitely the right way to go. It's a great lesson to keep in mind with react, I was under the slight impression that it was the code and not the test that was causing this to be such a difficult issue so its great to get a solution to that.